# Non-3-colorable planar 6-vertex graph?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

There are $112$ non-isomorphic $6$-vertex planar connected graphs, $81$ of which are $3$-colorable.

I'm searching for one example of an ($n\geq 6$-vertex planar connected graph:

a) that does not contain an [even-vertex wheel graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/WheelGraphs_1001.gif): (W4, W6, W8, W10, etc.)

b) whose vertices are not $3$-colorable

I know that there are plenty of examples, but I can't come up with any.

Comment: How do you know there are plenty of examples?

Comment: related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.7120.pdf

Comment: @HenningMakholm The paper provided [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/78a2/bbadb5f83b25a2f91e05f5237ca7e6c65c61.pdf) by Malyshev.

Comment: when you say it contains an even-vertex wheel graph do you mean as an induced subgraph or just as a subgraph?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I should have clarified: as an induced subgraph.

Comment: although now that I think of it, if a planar graph contains a wheel as a subgraph then it also contains a wheel as an induced subgraph.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there's 99 planar connected 6-vertex graphs. The number 112 that you've given incudes non-planar graphs. Also a quick glance at the paper you cited suggests that it does not assume planarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generated image of all 99 **planar** connected 6-vertex graphs:

The non-colorable ones have been painted with red vertices. None of them satisfy condition a).

[image: all 99 planar connected 6-vertex graphs]

And, there's an image of all 112 (possibly non-planar) connected 6-vertex graphs (note that the enumeration does not match):

Even here, I can't find any graph that satisfies both a) and b).

[image: all 112 connected 6-vertex graphs]

So, for $n=6$, there's no such example. For $n=7$, I found several, including these beauties:

```
                       o-----------o
      o               / \         / \
     /|\             /   \       /   \
    / | \           /     o     o     \
   o--o--o         /   .-  \   /  -.   \
   |\   /|        /. -      \ /      - .\
   | \ / |       o-----------o-----------o
   |  o  |
   | / \ |
   |/   \|
   o-----o
```

Comment: I tried different visualization algorithms to make it easier to spot the wheels. Here are the results.
Planar: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVqJG.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3WgV.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLSh6.png) All: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAxFn.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0zAP.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckLrF.png)

Comment: Is brute force the only viable strategy in order to find a wheel (or 4-clique) in a given graph?

Comment: @EmmaKrentz I'm not an expert in graph theory, so I don't know.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!